# group by clause in JPQL query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, jpql

I've a JPQL query which returns result without aggregates

```
public List<Transaction> getProjTransactionsByParametersId(Long id){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("FROM Transaction AS t WHERE t.account.id = :id and status = 0");

        Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString(), Transaction.class)
                .setParameter("id", id);

        List<Transaction> projTransactions = q.getResultList();

        return projTransactions;
    }
```

How can I incorporate group by here? I want somethinf like:

```
public List<Transaction> getProjTransactionsByParametersId(Long id){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT sum(t.amount), t.valueDate FROM Transaction AS t WHERE t.account.id = :id and status = 0 GROUP BY t.valueDate");

        Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString(), Transaction.class)
                .setParameter("id", id);

        List<Transaction> projTransactions = q.getResultList();

        return projTransactions;
    }
```

In this case, do I have to create some new field for that `sum` aggregate in `Transaction` mapping? I've read literature from other sources, but I couldn't understand logic.

For instance for valueDate in mapping I have getter which returns its value into my table. What about this aggregate column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give it an alias, like `sum(t.amount) as amountSum`. Then read read the values from the list of arrays (or use other similar [alternatives](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-select)):

```
List<Object[]> projTransactions = q.getResultList();
for (Object[] objects : projTransactions) {
   Number amountSum = (Number) objects[0]; // Use appropriate data type
   Date valueDate = (Date) objects[1];
}
```

Also, remove the (wrong) class argument from the query creation method:

`Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString())`

Comment: It throws an exception here, Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString())

Comment: What is the stacktrace? PS I edited my answer to point out that you do not need the class argument in this case.

Comment: exactly what I need. I was due to that class part. Thanks